# remove other tabs in new wordpress media gallery

Tags: filters, capabilities

I recently updated my WordPress site into the latest WordPress version, and i added a code to my `functions.php` that would add a capability to subscriber to upload using WordPress media upload. I successfully remove the media library tabs on the later version of WordPress but when I updated the version it seems like the code does not work anymore. Any ideas how to fix this?

This is the previous code which I googled before:

```
function remove_medialibrary_tab($tabs){
  if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || !current_user_can( 'editor' ) || !current_user_can( 'contibutor' ) || !current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
    unset($tabs['library']);
    return $tabs;
  } else {
    return $tabs;
  }
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs','remove_medialibrary_tab');

if ( !current_user_can('upload_files') ){
    add_action('init', 'allow_user_to_upload');
}

function allow_user_to_upload() {
    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    $subscriber->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide the *Media Library* submenu:

[image: Media Library submenu]

you can do it via the `admin_menu` action:

```
function wpse85351_hide_submenus() {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_posts')){
           global $submenu;
           unset($submenu['upload.php'][5]); // hide the Media Library
      }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse85351_hide_submenus');
```

If you want to change/remove the Media strings:

[image: Media strings]

you can use the `media_view_strings` filter:

```
function wpse85351_media_strings($strings) {
    // only for subscribers:
    if(!current_user_can('edit_posts')){
        // remove "mediaLibraryTitle"
        unset($strings["mediaLibraryTitle"]);
    }
    return $strings;
}
add_filter('media_view_strings','wpse85351_media_strings');
```

You can use

```
!current_user_can('edit_posts')
```

instead of

```
!current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || !current_user_can( 'editor' ) || !current_user_can( 'contibutor' ) || !current_user_can( 'author' )
```

to restrict it only to "subscribers".

Here is the array of all the *Media View Strings* that you can unset or change to your needs:

```
Array
(
    [url] => URL
    [addMedia] => Add Media
    [search] => Search
    [select] => Select
    [cancel] => Cancel
    [selected] => %d selected
    [dragInfo] => Drag and drop to reorder images.
    [uploadFilesTitle] => Upload Files
    [uploadImagesTitle] => Upload Images
    [mediaLibraryTitle] => Media Library
    [insertMediaTitle] => Insert Media
    [createNewGallery] => Create a new gallery
    [returnToLibrary] => &#8592; Return to library
    [allMediaItems] => All media items
    [noItemsFound] => No items found.
    [insertIntoPost] => Insert into post
    [uploadedToThisPost] => Uploaded to this post
    [warnDelete] => You are about to permanently delete this item.
  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete.
    [insertFromUrlTitle] => Insert from URL
    [setFeaturedImageTitle] => Set Featured Image
    [setFeaturedImage] => Set featured image
    [createGalleryTitle] => Create Gallery
    [editGalleryTitle] => Edit Gallery
    [cancelGalleryTitle] => &#8592; Cancel Gallery
    [insertGallery] => Insert gallery
    [updateGallery] => Update gallery
    [addToGallery] => Add to gallery
    [addToGalleryTitle] => Add to Gallery
    [reverseOrder] => Reverse order
)
```

Comment: thank you so much @birgire .. this save my day.. God bless.

Comment: Can I ask for more help?
How can I give access to all kind of users(even non logged in) to add media button in the **front end**?