# Customize WordPress Media Manager - Media Window

Tags: functions, filters, media-library, gallery

Im trying to customize the wordpress media manager "add media" window to get it as simple as possible to use. So i want to disable/ hide the following fields/ functions because i dont need some or others i handle with css.

1. I need to hide the tabs "create gallery", "set featured image" and import from url.
2. I want to hide/ disable the fields "url", "align", "link to" and "size" when i select an image.

Any idea how i can do that with a function, css or a plugin? I found some code-snippets to hide some tabs in functions.php but they didnt work in my wordpress v 4.3.1.

Thanks four your help and best regards.
Pascal

Comment: This [thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85351/remove-other-tabs-in-new-wordpress-media-gallery) might help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: These filters are not working. Maybe they are to old.

Comment: I solved the problem with a specific backend css with which i hide all the fields i dont want to show. Probably thats actually the best solution. If someone has an idea to solve this with filters i would be intrested in.