# remove links in pop-up media gallery

Tags: uploads, media-modal

Is it possible to remove certain links in the pop-up media upload screen? Is there a filter for the output of those links?

We need to remove the links crossed out in this screenshot:[image]

We can hide them with css, but was wondering if there is a hook.

Comment: Wonder if this 11years old way still works https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85381/26350 :-)

Comment: Thanks, but the `media_view_strings` filter does not work for the "Add Media" popup shown via `wp_editor`.